# How can I make language translation integration in pdf reader? Is there any Option?

Tags: pdf, language-translation

I am a Portuguese learner and also a engineering student with lectures in Portuguese which is a big headache. I frequently need to look over Portuguese files provided by professors. I wish there could be a pdf reader that has a translation facility so that every time I had a doubt I could just right click over or something like that to get english translation of it. Is there any option rather than just copying the words and making google translate or whatever? It's becauses I need to read lot.

Comment: Consider this to be an additional incentive to learn Portuguese. If we consider Google Translation as state of the art, you can imagine how complex the whole project would be. Assuming that the texts you get from your professors need to be understood accurately, you can (still) forget about any "machine translation" to provide adequate results.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Max. I realize this but I don't have that problem in figuring out the translated stuffs that results in some different sense. The problem is only with the words that arises at times in the texts. I believe I could get the track over things quickly if I had something as I mentioned previously. What say?